# Conversion of SQL Server stored procedure to a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert a stored procedure to a SQL query.

Here is the stored procedure in simple format:

```
SELECT
    table1.* 
INTO 
    #raw_data
FROM 
    table_1 WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE 
    (a lot of conditions and filtering follows)

SELECT
    xyz,
    pqr,
    (SELECT (something)
     FROM #raw_data aa
     WHERE aa.id1 = a.id1
       AND aa.id2 = a.id2
       ...)
INTO 
    #temp_data
FROM 
    #raw_data a
JOIN 
    table_2 b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.xid = b.xid
```

To convert this stored procedure into a SQL query, can I replace all the `#raw_data` in the second `SELECT` statement with:

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table_1 WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE (a lot of conditions and filtering follows)
```

I would like to know if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Why have you tagged the question MySQL, when the syntax is clearly SQL Server?

Comment: Why do you want to use `NOLOCK` everywhere? Are you aware of it's implications? You would be better off showing us the entirity of your SP, not a snippet; it's impossible for us to tell you how to convert the statements into a single query without all the statements.

Comment: Easiest way is probably to replace the temp table with a [CTE](https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-common-table-expressions-ctes/).

Comment: well a stored procedure make it easy to execute with a exec your_procedure_name param1, param2.... to turn it into a query ... simply copy the query and use as is.. no need to remove any temp tables and the sql query works just fine as is.. why make it convoluted?

Comment: And I would ask:  Why was it so convoluted to begin with?  Maybe there's something critical not being shared in the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you turned it into...

```
SELECT xyz
, pqr
, (
    SELECT (something)
    FROM (
    SELECT table_1.*
        FROM table_1 WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE (a lot of conditions and filtering follows)
    ) aa
    WHERE aa.id1 = a.id1
    AND aa.id2 = a.id2
    ...
)

INTO #temp_data

FROM (
    SELECT table_1.*
    FROM table_1 WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE (a lot of conditions and filtering follows)
  ) a
  inner JOIN table_2 b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.xid = b.xid
```

But you should keep going.  The correlated subquery is not needed in this case.  It doesn't appear to add any value.  It makes the query more complicated.  It also slows it down since the subquery must be run once for every row in the outer query.  To take advantage of SQL Server's ability to join sets of data en masse...

```
SELECT xyz
, pqr
, aa.something

INTO #temp_data

FROM (
    SELECT table_1.*
    FROM table_1 WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE (a lot of conditions and filtering follows)
  ) a
  inner join (
    SELECT table_1.*
    FROM table_1 WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE (a lot of conditions and filtering follows)
  ) aa on aa.id1 = a.id1
      and aa.id2 = a.id2
      ...
  inner JOIN table_2 b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.xid = b.xid
```

Assuming you're always joining table_1 to table_1 by using the same column on both sides of the join, as in your code) you may be able to simplify further.  Be careful here.  I assume that xid is unique or is included in the join between `a` and `aa`.  If it is not, you'll want to stop here.

So, if you can simplify further, the next step is...

```
SELECT xyz
, pqr
, a.something

INTO #temp_data

FROM (
    SELECT table_1.*
    FROM table_1 WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE (a lot of conditions and filtering follows)
  ) a
  inner JOIN table_2 b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.xid = b.xid
```

...and can be simplified to...

```
SELECT xyz
, pqr
, a.something

INTO #temp_data

FROM table_1 a WITH (NOLOCK)
  inner JOIN table_2 b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.xid = b.xid

WHERE (a lot of conditions and filtering follows)
```

It looks like there may be considerably more complexity that you didn't share (the three dots of uncertainty).

```
WHERE aa.id1 = a.id1
  AND aa.id2 = a.id2
  ...
```

Your mileage may vary.